# How to delete uploaded files from community attachements

Tags: case, contentdocumentlink

I am uploading pdf into the attachement from community. So after uploading the pdf. Pdf will create a case into the salesforce org. So i want that after creating the case in custom object called audit process. That pdf should be deleted from community notes and attachement but it should not be deleted from org case attachement. Here in below code i am fetching ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion and i am deleting that ContentDocumentId. but the pdf were deleted from community notes and attachement and also from  case attachement.

Below is the trigger code to create a case from the pdf

```
trigger InitiateAuditProcess on Audit_Project__c (before update) {
    Audit_Project__c auditProcess = Trigger.New[0];

    if(auditProcess.Status__c == 'Data Submitted'){


          if(HelperClass.firstRun)
          {


        if( Trigger.oldMap.get( auditProcess.Id ).Status__c != Trigger.newMap.get( auditProcess.Id ).Status__c ){

            List <ContentVersion> contentVersions = [select Id, LastModifiedById, PathonClient, VERSIONDATA , Title from ContentVersion where FIRSTPUBLISHLOCATIONID =: auditProcess.Id];

            if(contentVersions != null){

                for(ContentVersion cv : contentVersions){

                    String fileName;

                    fileName = cv.PathOnClient;


                    if(fileName.contains('_')){
                        Integer lastIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('_');

                        String householdLastName  = fileName.substring(0, lastIndex);
                        String unit = fileName.substring(lastIndex + 1,fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

                        if(householdLastName != null && unit != null){

                            Case obj = new Case(); 
                            obj.Effective_Date_Certification__c = System.today();
                            obj.Origin = 'Email';
                            obj.PropertyCase__c= auditProcess.PropertyCase__c;
                            obj.Income_Set_Aside__c = 0;
                            obj.House_hold_name__c = '1';
                            obj.Bedroom_Size__c = '1 BR';
                            obj.Certified_Income__c = 0;
                            obj.Household__c = householdLastName ;
                            obj.Property_Staff_Name__c = auditProcess.Property_Staff_Name__c;
                            obj.Unit__c = unit; 
                            obj.Audit_Request_Name__c = auditProcess.Id;

                            insert obj;

                             ContentVersion cvInsert = new ContentVersion();

                            cvInsert.PathOnClient = cv.PathOnClient;

                            cvInsert.Title = cv.Title;
                            cvInsert.FirstPublishLocationId = obj.Id;
                            cvInsert.VersionData = cv.VersionData;

                            insert cvInsert;


                          List<ContentDocument> listToDelete = new List<ContentDocument>();

                          for (ContentVersion conver : [
      SELECT
        id,  ContentDocumentId
      FROM ContentVersion
      WHERE FIRSTPUBLISHLOCATIONID =: auditProcess.Id
  ]) 


                            {
    listToDelete.add(new ContentDocument(
        Id = conver.ContentDocumentId
    ));

  }         
       delete listToDelete;






                        }else{

                            Integer indexOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                            String nameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, indexOfDot);
                            String extension = fileName.substring(indexOfDot + 1 , fileName.length() -1 );

                            cv.Title = nameWithoutExt + '_Error' ;

                            update cv;


                        }
                    }else{

                        Integer indexOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                        String nameWithoutExt = fileName.substring(0, indexOfDot);
                        String extension = fileName.substring(indexOfDot + 1 , fileName.length() -1 );
                        cv.Title = nameWithoutExt + '_Error' ;

                        update cv;

                    }


                }

            }
        }

                HelperClass.firstRun = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the ContentDocument, You should delete ContentDocumentLink associated with that ContentDocument.

[ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) represents a document that has been uploaded to a library in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files.

[ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file and where it's shared. A file can be shared with other users, groups, records, and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

For Example:-

To query for a file is sharing to

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.Name, LinkedEntity.Type, ShareType, Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0690k000000TzTMAA0'
```